# Using filtered records from a form in a query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, dao

I have a large table. I am making a form that displays the table, and allows the user to use Access' standard filters on many different fields to choose only some of the data. Then, after the user has used the filters to choose only some of the data, I want to be able to include only the resulting recordset (and not the entire original table) in various queries.

I'm not sure if there's a way I can directly reference the form's underlying recordset in a query.

The obvious thing would be to use vba to iterate through the recordset, and either fill a temporary table with it that would be used in the queries, or directly do what I want with the data without using sql. But I believe iterating through a recordset is considerably slower than a query. Is there some way that I can reference a form's recordset directly from within a query, or dump the entire contents of the recordset into a temporary table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Form.RecordsetClone` will copy the subform's recordset and include any filters applied through the Access' built-in filters.

Note: the `Form.` is standard and does not refer to your form. So your reference would need to be `Me!SubformName!Form.RecordsetClone` if triggered from the main form. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835062.aspx)

After you  create a clone, it seems you can use sql to drop the recordset into a temp table. But as @Andre mentioned, adding the PK only would be ideal to reduce load in large recordsets. The SQL string creation I found is simply:

`sql = "INSERT INTO TEMPTable VALUES" & rs.Fields("YourPKFieldNameFromSUBFORM")`

Assuming `sql` and `rs` have been declared as a string and your cloned recordset respectively, and TEMPTable has already been created with one column for your PK. [Source: #5](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-recordset/) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193203.aspx)  However, you will still need to loop through each record of the clone, as the sql statement only outputs a single row at a time.

Comment: I think too that `RecordsetClone` is the way to go, but he will still have to insert the data into a temporary table (either the PKs only and then join it to the main table, or all columns).

Comment: In other words, there's no way to directly get the `RecordsetClone` directly into a table, and I have to iterate through it and manually insert it, as I suggested in my question?

Comment: @clum It looks that way. :( I tried using the sql string to dump all rows but it outputs only the first record. You will need to loop to get all of the values from your clone into your table.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to Christopher D.'s answer, here is the final code I ended up using:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM FilteredJobs"
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = Search_subform.Form.RecordsetClone
rs.MoveFirst
While Not rs.EOF
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO FilteredJobs VALUES (" & rs.Fields("JobID") & ")"
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: An important note: This worked fine during development when using a small subset of data. When used in real life, this takes a very long time when there is still a large dataset (such as when there are no filters or barely limiting filters). I still don't have a good solution for this.